# How do I use FTP via the command line to download all files?

Tags: terminal, file-transfer, ftp

I tried to use Filezilla and Cyberduck for file transfer over a simple FTP server. The problems I have is:

- Filezilla: When I use it for file transferring, I check the "Activity Monitor", the "% CPU" usage is like 150% - 200%. I was shocked. My mac start to become lag, so I stop it.
- Cyberduck: When I download a folder from ftp, about 60mb, inside have small files (*.php, *.jpg etc). It took about 8 hours to download the files(there is a time indication of how much time left in cyberduck). If I use filezilla, it only takes about 1-3 mins. I notice, when using Cyberduck, it keep setting the permissions first, not really transfer the files directly. And it took quite long.

Thus, I went to google, and I found that mac can use Terminal to connect to ftp server and download files.

```
ftp hostname
mget * (download all the files)
```

Now, another problem, let say, in my ftp I have:

```
- blog(folder)
    - php(folder)
    - img(folder)
- others folder
```

I want to download "blog" and its subsequent folders and files. Can I do it in 1 command line? If no, how do you download my "blog" folder?

I remember in unix/linux command, there is something like this:

```
- remove -R blba
```

which remove the folder blba recursively (its subsequent folders and files), I wonder if mac's terminal ftp command can support this.

Please advise

Comment: Sounds like Cyberduck isn't running in multithreaded mode. Under Preferences -> Transfers tab make sure 'Transfer Files:' is set to 'Open new connection'. Under the Bandwidth tab make sure the download limit is set to Unlimited Bandwidth.

Answer (score 5):

The curl program could help you download an FTP file, but it specializes in one-off URLs (http, ftp, etc). It is possible to use Perl to script something up to list then download, but its much easier to use wget!

However, wget is not a standard program of OSX so you will need to manually download, compile, and install it (relatively easy task, as long as you have Xcode installed.)

1. [Install Xcode from the App Store](http://developer.apple.com/xcode/).
2. [Download wget source](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/wget/wget-latest.tar.gz)
3. Open a Terminal into the directory you saved the source.

Run the following commands:

```
    $ tar xfvz wget-latest.tar.gz
    $ cd wget-*
    $ ./configure && make
```

The wget binary will be produced in a src subdirectory. From here you can run the binary directly as `./src/wget` or install into /usr/local/bin:

```
    $ sudo make install
```

Now, you only need to run `wget -r  ftp://username:passwd@server/path/to/download` and your FTP site will be recursively downloaded from that path!

Just remember that the /path/to/download is relative to the username you login with... and FTP passwords are notoriously unsecure :)

Comment: Optionally: install Xcode, [install homebrew](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew), do `brew install wget`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to proceed without Xcode you may also use [curlmirror](http://curl.haxx.se/programs/curlmirror.txt) which builds on `curl` which is already supplied with OSX. In case you get the script from the web site linked above, you have to rename the first line to `#!/usr/bin/perl` in a text editor of your choice.

Answer (score 1):

the standard ftp doesn't have "recursive download" functionality. but `ncftp` has.  Please try it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you switch to the latest snapshot build of Cyberduck which should improve download transfer initialization.